# Mobile Web app scroll issue, especially on iOS webkit

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, scroll, vuetify.js, webkit

In my vuejs project, sometimes, a scroll is not working for seconds, then working again in specific views.

It occurs on chrome, and iOS webkit, and is easily found some pages with input tags and v-textfield. (It's web app.)

Please note the below conditions and give a piece of advice.

- Vuejs 3.0, using Vuetify 3.0 for some parts (Version: "vue": "^3.2.13", "vuetify": "^3.0.0",)
- For a scroll, a height with vh, and overflow (auto and -x or -y scroll) are being used
- Easily found on iOS webit (A scroll & tested on iOS 15 or later),
  and it can be reproduced on chrome when set the screen as a mobile device, too

Here is a sample of the vue file, that has the issue.

```
<template>
  <div class="inner container editCar"> // height set by vh here.
    - header part   // height set fixed from top
   ...
    <div class="car_input-inner"> // input part - height, overflow set here
      <div class="car-input" >
         // Vuetify text feild
         // I'm new to Vuejs so leave some detail here, FYI.
          <v-text-field
            ref="registrationNumberField"
            outlined
            clearable
            hide-details
            type="text"
            v-model="binding.registrationNumber"
            @keydown.enter="util.handleFocus($event, unladenWeightField)" // From here, border-line changed by css
            @blur="resetBorderColor(registrationNumberField, LengthValid)"    
            @focus="applyBorderColor(registrationNumberField, LengthValid)"
            @click:clear="binding.registrationNumber = ''"
            maxlength="8"
            placeholder="car number (123가4567)"
            :class="{
              valid: binding.registrationNumber !== '' && LengthValid,
            }"
          />

        ... more simple v-text-field...

          <v-text-field
            style="margin-top: 1.2rem"
            ref="unladenWeightField"
            outlined
            hide-details
            type="number"
            v-model="binding.unladenWeight"
            @input="bindInput('unladenWeight', 5)"
            oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
            @keydown.enter="util.handleFocus($event, loadingWeightField)"
            @blur="resetBorderColor(unladenWeightField, true)"
            @focus="applyBorderColor(unladenWeightField, true)"
            maxlength="5"
            placeholder="Weight"
            :class="{
              valid: binding.unladenWeight !== '',
            }"
            suffix="t"
          />

        ... more simple v-text-field...

      </div>
    <div>
   ...
  - button group part (two buttons fixed from bottom)

</template>
```

FYI, a scroll only works in a `<div class="car_input-inner">` part as the rest parts are fixed

Any ideas and opinions are welcomed.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you solve it??

Comment: I printed Webkit's 'scrollView.contentOffset.y' in swift.
When scrolling the entire screen, the value is displayed in native, but
If only a specific part is scrolled, the value is not output in native.
Could this be related to the problem of not printing values ​​and intermittent scrolling?

Comment: No I haven't solve this problem. I've changed the view structure for a few times, so it sometimes got better somehow, but not resolved yet.

For your question, I am not 100% sure though that can be related. I tested a touch event and a scroll event, and when the issue occurs, there was no scroll issue, but a touch event

Comment: If anyone has had a similar experience, even if it's not the same, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

For unnatural scrolling behavior, this css line on your body or related section will fix it: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`